# Order ID sequence issue in Magento 1.9.2.4

Tags: database, magento-1

order ID 100000099 is missing in my magento admin, I do not know whether it is deleted by mistake or not.

[image]

When I open order no 100000100. In url, order id shows 10000099.
[image]

after order ID 10000099. all orders show like this sequence.

[image]

The wrong ID also shows in front-end my acccount.

[image]

kindly help me to resolve this issue.

Thank You

Comment: check in database sales_flat_order table the record is there?

Comment: @RamaChandran - I have checked in database sales_flat_order table. Order no 100000099 is not there

Comment: any backup database  please check and updated in sales_flat_* all tables

Comment: @RamaChandran - can i create new table in between order no 98  &  100 and add random data in this table

Comment: you can export 99 record from old database and insert in you table. it will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep it as it is! This is not an issue.

The order ID you see in your URL is the `entity_id` of your sales orders. The long number is the order `increment_id` that is visible on frontend. They have **not** to be identical.

You'll find a good explaination there: [Magento Order Number Issue](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/37017/magento-order-number-issue/37444)

Comment: Agreed. Order 100000099 was simply never completed,  as is most likely a stale quote,  or will still be completed. Carts usually have a 30 day lifetime,  unless cart session lifetime was changed. Orders are not necessarily in sequence. If that was the case until now, just dumb luck.