# Why some order id are skipping from admin panel Sales > Order

Tags: magento-1.9, database, sales-order, admin-panel, sales-quote

[image]

Why this number jumps from 189 to 191 ?

When i found this issue there were many missing order number.

Even i got solution that some order with status : pending or hold cant be seen in the admin panel order list, and are reserved.

And present in the database, we can see those value in the database with table sales_flat_order and sales_flat_quote.

But there are some missing order number which are not found-able in admin as well as in both the tables  sales_flat_order and sales_flat_quote.

Means to say missing from admin, quote and order.

Why this skipping order issue i am facing with magento 1.9 ? Please help if there is any solution exits. Thank you.

Comment: Please refer to this excellent explanation: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/37444/5972