# Increment id is not continuous in magento2

Tags: magento2, database, grid, order-grid, increment-id

I have got a strange issue when I create a new product in backend my id is incremented +2 see the below image

[image]

if i place the order .my order id also incremented +2 see the below image

[image]

in my custom grid also my id becomes incremented by two. Did anyone face this issue?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: This link (Magento1) has approx similar issue reported though not so frequent. But I think you will have some hint from here- https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/37017/magento-order-number-issue

Comment: I have checked this but its not working

Comment: Hey @chris, did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Look in `sales_sequence_meta` table for entity_type order ID, then look in `sales_sequence_profile` table for column named `step`. Default value should be `1`

Comment: i can't understand can u explain briefly

Comment: if you do not have many changes in your store, just check in table `sales_sequence_profile` row with `profile_id = 1`. Column `step` should be set to `1`