# Skipping order id by 1 in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, orders

In our **Magento 2 store** suddenly **order id** has started skipping order id by 1.

Here is the order id example:

> 000000011 
>  000000013 
>  000000015 
>  000000017 
>  000000019

I went through multiple posts like [magento-order-number-issue](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/37017/magento-order-number-issue) and [magento-order-id-increment-jumps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10935117/magento-order-id-increment-jumps), and they say like due to failed/in-complete payment, or customer doesn't complete all checkout steps this issue might occur.

So my question is, it should happen only in the mentioned scenarios and from next order it should work fine if there isn't any issue, but in my case it always skips 1 order. I have observed this for around 100 orders.

Few posts also suggest due to abandoned cart this issue might occur so I have truncated quote tables using below query, still issue exists.

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

TRUNCATE TABLE `quote`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_address`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_address_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_id_mask`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_item_option`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_payment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_shipping_rate`;

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

How I can fix this?

Comment: do you have any extensions that might affect the orders? There is a chance that one extension calls `reserveOrderId` whithout checking if the quote has already a reserved order id. Try disabling all custom extensions and see if it happens.

Comment: can you please mention which payment getaway/extension you are using. Sometime payment extension reserve the order Id before redirecting to payment get way and after successful payment  order will created with that reserve order id.

Comment: @Marius, I do have a module which modifies quote and order table. I will try disabling it, if it works.

Comment: @PritamInfo24, I am using PayUMoney payment gateway. Though order is placed in Magento as soon as I click "Place Order" button.

Comment: I think that assumption posted by Marius is the right way to find the problem. I would suggest to search all your source code for the calls of the method `setReservedOrderId($reservedOrderId)` that might guide you to the right point. If you have the possibility, I would suggest to create a plugin and hook it before that method to log all the calls with backtrace, that might give you a hint where the calls come from

Comment: I have checked custom modules and there isn't something in any module which is setting reserved order id. Also this module was working fine and suddenly it started skipping order ids on production site. On staging site, it still works fine as expected.

Comment: @amitshree I had same issue in braintree payment once, and fixed by upgrading extension.

Comment: Sometimes this type of situation happens when checkout failure when placing the order. do you have? Please check the error log

Comment: @BirjitsinhZala, I have placed two consecutive successful orders and there wasn't any issue. I do not see anything in log also.

Comment: I have download production db and configured it in my local system. In my local system everything works fine again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After digging into the some articles I figured out, there is no other way to make increment by 2 than this:

Magento stores order auto increment id in `sequence_order_1` or `sequence_order_2` table, based on stores. So it uses only **1** increment id by default. Unless someone change `auto_increment_increment` value of database like:

```
SET @@auto_increment_increment=2;
```

Try this command and see if your auto increment value is fixed:

```
SET @@auto_increment_increment=1;
```

I didn't find any other solution.

**Note: If you are getting this issue on order increment id and it is occurring due to auto increment value, then it would be occurring on all tables, because it's a global variable**

Just wanted to help :)

Comment: Few days ago I have updated auto_increment for `sequence_order_1` table.  After changing that, incremental id was in sequence, but later on this issue started happening.

Comment: I think @Kamal Paliwal has the point, you need to check sales_sequence_profile value, but meta value could be anything, it could be 6

Comment: In `sequence_order_1` table `AUTO_INCREMENT` value is `90691` but  last `sequence_value ` is `90689` in that table.

Comment: That's weird. Have you tried `SET @@auto_increment_increment=1;` on database?

Comment: Thanks Shoaib. That has helped me in the right direction to find the issue. Problem was that `auto-increment-increment = 2` was set in `/etc/my.cnf` file. After updating it, issue is resolved.

Comment: That's great. You are welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

Do check the value of `step` column in `sales_sequence_profile` table for `meta_id` (5 might be different but you need to check for the `order` one)

Comment: You have the point, but in my case, meta value is 6. Good answer

Comment: It might be due to different Magento versions

Comment: I see value of `step` column is `1` for all rows in `sales_sequence_profile` table.